# How to enable numerical feature drift?

Tags: tensorflow-data-validation

I want to enable numerical feature drift without setting a domain. Ex: I am scoring customers based on age and in my training set I had a uniform distribution of the variable. Now, in my serving data, all customers are in their 50's (a domain won't catch such shift change). Is there any option to flag such behavior that would call for a re-training in tfdv ?

I tried giving tfdv two distributions N(0,1) and N(10,1) but no anomalies where detected.

EDIT : Drift only works for Categorical features.

Answer (score 0):

Drifts for numerical features is in development right now and are going to be supported in the next version of tfdv (after 0.24.1). To do that you will have to use JSD instead of infinity norm.

Answer (score 0):

TFDV has added a new feature that allows us to detect skew for numeric features. specify a `jensen_shannon_divergence` threshold instead of an `infinity_norm` threshold in the `skew_comparator`.

Example:

```
tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'total_actions').skew_comparator.jensen_shannon_divergence.threshold = 0.01
```

You can check more about it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/get_started#checking_data_skew_and_drift